# javascript alphabetical order

Tags: javascript, alphabetical-sort, alphabetized

the idea is to sort everything in alphabetical order, when i use id, it works perfect, but when i use the name attribute it does not work

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Retrieving a Textbox Value Example</title>

</head>
<body>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="25" name="txt2"></textarea>
    <br />
    <textarea rows="5" cols="25" name="txt3"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Set Values" onclick="setValues()" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
     function setValues() {
      var oTextbox2= document.getElementsByName("txt2")[0];   
      oTextbox2 = oTextbox2.value.split(" ").sort();

      var oTextbox3 = document.getElementsByName("txt3")[0]; 
      oTextbox3.value = oTextbox2;
    } 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wKDV6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
  oTextbox2 = oTextbox2.value.split(" ").sort();
```

to:

```
  oTextbox2 = oTextbox2.value.split(" ").sort().join(" ");
```

You need to use `.join()` to turn the sorted array back into a string.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/wKDV6/1/)

Comment: if tried the .join(), but does not work for me,     i should also submit in csv form, for example: ant,badger,cattle,zoo in oTextbox3